# How to list the methods associated with a Jquery object

Tags: jquery, methods, dir

I'm learning JQuery, and I'm looking for a way to view the methods an object as associated with it after its created, much like python's dir().

Answer (score 9):

This is assuming you loaded jquery, are using firefox or chrome (for console), and have a document.ready method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($('body'));
});
```

In console, you should see the selector Object you created with jquery. Click on that to view it's instance data.  When you view that selector Object, you will see a list of all jquery methods available to act on that selector Object.

You should be able to view something like this:
[image: console.log of jquery methods within selector]

BTW, you should be able to click on any method name to see it's code in console.